# How to re-organize the charts in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, pie-chart

I am using R Shiny to visualize data as some pie charts using Plotly package. The problem is that I would like to re-size the pie charts and navigate them horizontally not vertically, picture is shown below.

I will appreciate for helps experts!

Here is the code

```
#UI part
dashboardBody(
fluidRow(
  plotlyOutput("PieDistribution"),
  plotlyOutput("PieHealth")
)

#server part
output$PieDistribution <- renderPlotly({
plot_ly(PD, labels = ~PD$VP, values = ~PD$V1, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'percent',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(PD$VP),
        marker = list(colors = colors,
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1))) %>%
  layout(title = 'Project Distribution by Vice President',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE,
         legend = list(x = 50, y = 0.5))
  })

output$PieHealth <- renderPlotly({
plot_ly(PD2, labels = ~PD2$HealthName, values = ~PD2$V1, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'percent',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(PD2$HealthName),
        marker = list(colors = c('#229954', '#d32f2f','#ffc107'),
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1))) %>%
  layout(title = "Project Health",
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE)
})
```

[Image of the pie charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKBno.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new columns within fluidrow in your ui. Something like:

```
fluidRow(column(6,
  plotlyOutput("PieDistribution")),
column(6,
  plotlyOutput("PieHealth"))
)
```